# Reducing variables before LASSO

Tags: feature-selection, lasso

I have around 1200 cases, 150 events, each with roughly 100 predictors. Some of the predictors are highly correlated, and the end-game is to derive a predictive model with as few predictors as possible (needs to be reported and easy to use for clinicians/researchers). Therefore LASSO seemed like a good option due to it actually removing predictors compared to for example Ridge regression.

However, due to the high correlation between many of the predictors I have removed some variables pre-LASSO via stuff like VIF, and other techniques. In turn, before I do the LASSO regression, I end up with 7 predictors, which is quite a reduction.

After doing LASSO I end up with 5 predictors.

However, if I don't do any of these variable selection techniques prior to the LASSO regression, and just do LASSO on all 100 predictors, I end up with one less predictor and a better AUC score actually.

I have no idea if I am just lucky, or whatever. But how should I go about this ? I have pretty much followed what other researchers in my field has done, but again, less predictors and a better AUC score (although that isn't everything, I know), is usually always the better option, or...?

Comment: Maybe tell us some more about `VIF, and other techniques`? VIF is not meant to be used for feature selection. Have you tried Elastic Net?

Comment: Well, VIF is used to remove very correlated predictors. And on top of having correlated predictors, some of them are even "in the same class", meaning, they are based on the same, but with a little difference, which means there is no reason to have both in the model. So when I have removed the highly correlated predictors via VIF, I use the likelihood ratio to remove the worst "in the same class" predictors as well.

Comment: I suppose by AUC you're referring to the "AUROC", area under the roc curve. Since you have 150 events out of 1200 cases, which is somehow unbalanced, you might want to check out the "AUPR", area under the precision-recall curve, too. It's a better metric if you have few positives in your data.